# jqGrid setGridParm does not return

Tags: jqgrid

In the following code the Var x=1 and x=x+1 code never runs - but if I put it before the setGridParm call it does. Ultimately I need to execute a function but this demonstrates the issue easier.
Running latest version jqGrid as of 5/23/22

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function projadd(mytable){
    var parms=JSON.parse($(mytable).jqGrid('getGridParam','parms'))
    var pointers=$("#"+parms.my_table).jqGrid('getGridParam','userData')
    var gridData=$(mytable).jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
    var next_proj_key=pointers.next_key
    var next_proj_no=pointers.next_row_number
    var nnextkey=parseInt(next_proj_key)+1
    var nnextrow=parseInt(next_proj_no)+1
    jQuery(mytable).jqGrid('editGridRow', 'new',{ closeAfterAdd:true,clearAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit: false,addedrow:'last',recreateForm:true,
                editData:{l1_key:next_proj_key,
                rownum:next_proj_no,
                next_upd_due:" ",
                issue_ct:"0",
                late_ct:"0",
                next_iss_no:"1",
                next_iss_key:"1"
                },
                afterComplete : function (response, postdata, formid) {pointers.next_key=nnextkey;
                                                                        update_proj(parms);
                                                                        pointers.next_row_number=nnextrow;
                                                                      $("#"+parms.l1.my_table).jqGrid('setGridParm',"userData",pointers);
                                                                      var x=1
                                                                      x=x+1
                                                                      }
                                                                }                                                       
                        )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there is a problem in the following expression:

```
$("#"+parms.l1.my_table).jqGrid('setGridParm',"userData",pointers);
```

Be a sure that the variable **parms.l1.my_table** exist and is valid.

This maybe causes error, which prevent executing of the commands after setGridParam

Another important error here is that setGridParam expect object as parameter (see docs) and not string.

The correct expression should be like this:

```
$("#"+parms.l1.my_table).jqGrid('setGridParm',{ "userData": pointers} );
```

Comment: Thank you Tony - I changed the syntax as you suggested - same behavior. Interestingly the call performs as expected - it just doesn't return. I have modified my code to work around this so resolution for me is not critical - don't know if anyone else has seen this issue.

Comment: Do you have check if the element **parms.l1.my_table**  exists?